# Webmail behind firewall

Tags: networking, apache2, email, firewall, nat

I hope someone can point me to a guide or help set up a mail server behind a pfSense firewall that would be separated from the web page. I am a relative newbie on Linux, so the more detailed, the better.

My situation is:

I have pfSense running as the firewall. I have three NICs in it; I am only using two (WAN and LAN).

I have a Raspberry Pi behind that running Apache2, and I have three websites running on it. I have them running with SSL certificates.

I have pfSense forwarding ports 80 and 443 to that apache server.

I brought up a virtual server running Ubuntu 20.04 to use as a mail server.

What I need to know how to do, if possible, is to get a mail server up and running on the virtual server and also be able to use webmail from that server. I don't know how to accomplish this. So I am looking for help or a guide to accomplish it since I can't NAT the ports for HTTP and HTTP to multiple servers, and I haven't had much luck trying to Google a guide.

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to check https://workaround.org/ispmail/buster/ , not your exact situation but it might give you a good headstart. The tutorial is for Debian 10, but works fine at Ubuntu 20.04 too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to keep HTTP and HTTPS ports redirected to RPi, but you want to be able to somehow use webmail from the Ubuntu machine?

In that case you need to take advantage of the Apache web server proxying capability. You can set up a particular subdomain or URL on your Apache server to "forward" a connection to a completely different website. Here's the guide on setting this up: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

Of course for the mail server itself, you need to forward ports 25/587/465 (for SMTP) and 143/993 (for IMAP) to the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Yup that's what I want to do. The ports for mail I can set up in the firewall, it is just the HTTP and HTTPS that I wasn't sure what to do with since I don't want to change them from the RPi. I will check out that reverse proxy and hope it's not too complicated :) Thank you.